# How to handle "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning" error while using AWS-SDK in NodeJs/TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-sdk

I am using `aws-sdk` to empty S3 bucket. My code does the job but I am getting `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` error. What I understood from this error is, either error occurred inside `async` function where there is no catch block, or rejected promise was not handled with `.catch()`.

I have catch block and I think I am handling the error gracefully but still getting this error so need to understand where I am making mistake(s).

Any suggestions would be helpful.

**Code:**

```
async emptyS3Bucket(bucketName: string) {
  try {

    await this.deleteVersions(bucketName);

    await this.deleteMarkers(bucketName);

    await this.deleteContents(bucketName);

  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}

private async deleteVersions(bucketName: string) {

    await this.s3
      .listObjectVersions({ Bucket: bucketName })
      .promise()
      .then( async (data) => {
        await this.deleteObjects(data.Versions, bucketName);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throw error;
      });
  }

  private async deleteMarkers(bucketName: string) {

    await this.s3
      .listObjectVersions({ Bucket: bucketName })
      .promise()
      .then( async (data) => {
        await this.deleteObjects(data.DeleteMarkers, bucketName);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throw error;
      });
  }

  private async deleteContents(bucketName: string) {

    await this.s3
    .listObjectsV2( { Bucket: bucketName })
    .promise()
    .then( async (data) => {
      await this.deleteObjects(data.Contents, bucketName);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
       throw error;
    });
  }

  private async deleteObjects(objects: any, bucketName: string) {
  try {
    const deleteParams = {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Delete: { Objects: [] }
    };

    deleteParams.Delete.Objects = objects.map(({ Key, VersionId }) => ({ Key, VersionId }));

    await this.s3.deleteObjects(deleteParams)
    .promise().
    then((data) => {
      // DO SOMETHING
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      throw error;
    });

  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the cause of your issue, but it seems pointless to use async/await keywords in simple, single-path functions. The one that waits for multiple promises is okay, but for instance the delete one can be `.then(data => this.deleteObjects(data.Versions, bucketName)`

Comment: @Katana314 I tried that too where I received same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you do not chain properly the promises.

```
await this.s3
  .listObjectVersions({ Bucket: bucketName })
  .promise()
  .then( async data => {
    // this line will not bet catched in the following catch,
    // because you do not redurn the result of the await,
    // so this is most likely the case why you have unhandled rejections.
      await this.deleteObjects(data.DeleteMarkers, bucketName);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    throw error;
  });
```

The solution is to return the result of the await:

```
return this.deleteObjects(data.DeleteMarkers, bucketName);
```

This will enable the chaining to work because a return from a then is also a promise.

Comment: So in this case, it is okay if I throw error in catch block? Let me test that. Also, I'll add logging.

Comment: If you throw an error it needs someone to catch it so you need the final handler `process.on('unhandledRejection')` ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug error in `emptyS3Bucket` function instead of throwing it from catch block. Rewrite your code like this and you will no longer receive UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning error:

```
async emptyS3Bucket(bucketName: string) {
  try {

    await this.deleteVersions(bucketName);

    await this.deleteMarkers(bucketName);

    await this.deleteContents(bucketName);

  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error occured in emptyS3Bucket', error)
  }
}

private async deleteVersions(bucketName: string) {
  const data = await this.s3.listObjectVersions({
    Bucket: bucketName
  }).promise();

  return this.deleteObjects(data.Versions, bucketName);
}

private async deleteMarkers(bucketName: string) {
  const data = await this.s3.listObjectVersions({
    Bucket: bucketName
  }).promise();

  return this.deleteObjects(data.DeleteMarkers, bucketName);
}

private async deleteContents(bucketName: string) {
  const data = await this.s3.listObjectsV2({
    Bucket: bucketName
  }).promise();

  return this.deleteObjects(data.Contents, bucketName);
}

private async deleteObjects(objects: any, bucketName: string) {
  const Objects = objects.map(({
    Key,
    VersionId
  }) => ({
    Key,
    VersionId
  }));

  const deleteParams = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Delete: {
      Objects
    }
  };

  return this.s3.deleteObjects(deleteParams).promise()
}
```

Comment: So where should I throw the error? In parent method (i.e. `emptyBucket`) where I am calling these `private functions`?

Comment: If you use these private functions in `emptyS3Bucket` function only, you can throw errors in private functions and write `console.log('Error occured in  emptyS3Bucket', error)` in parent function and this will solve your problem

Comment: Could you give me an example? When you say `you can throw errors in private functions`, I do not understand. I thought that was the problem. Am I missing something?

Comment: This does resolves the error but wonder how can I pass this error to handler. I mean we are just logging the error. Let me see what gets passed to handler in this case and I'll go from there. Thank you, this is very helpful though.